# I'm trying to run an if-then true-false statement. How, I continuously receive errors when attempting to do so

Tags: python, sequence

I'm trying to run an if-then true-false statement. How, I continuously receive errors when attempting to do so.

This is what I have so far.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

dna2rna =  {'A':'U', 'T':'A', 'C':'G', 'G':'C'}
def dna2rna(seq):
    return ''

codon2aa = {"AAA":"K", "AAC":"N", "AAG":"K", "AAU":"N", 
            "ACA":"T", "ACC":"T", "ACG":"T", "ACU":"T", 
            "AGA":"R", "AGC":"S", "AGG":"R", "AGU":"S", 
            "AUA":"I", "AUC":"I", "AUG":"M", "AUU":"I", 

            "CAA":"Q", "CAC":"H", "CAG":"Q", "CAU":"H", 
            "CCA":"P", "CCC":"P", "CCG":"P", "CCU":"P", 
            "CGA":"R", "CGC":"R", "CGG":"R", "CGU":"R", 
            "CUA":"L", "CUC":"L", "CUG":"L", "CUU":"L", 

            "GAA":"E", "GAC":"D", "GAG":"E", "GAU":"D", 
            "GCA":"A", "GCC":"A", "GCG":"A", "GCU":"A", 
            "GGA":"G", "GGC":"G", "GGG":"G", "GGU":"G", 
            "GUA":"V", "GUC":"V", "GUG":"V", "GUU":"V", 

            "UAA":"_", "UAC":"Y", "UAG":"_", "UAU":"T", 
            "UCA":"S", "UCC":"S", "UCG":"S", "UCU":"S", 
            "UGA":"_", "UGC":"C", "UGG":"W", "UGU":"C", 
            "UUA":"L", "UUC":"F", "UUG":"L", "UUU":"F"}

rna = ('AUG').upper()
amino = ''

while rna:
    amino += codon2aa[rna[:3]]
    rna = rna[3:]

print(amino)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with urlopen('http://web.njit.edu/~kapleau/teach/current/bnfo135/sequence.gb') as conn:
        data = conn.readlines()

    lines = [line.strip() for line in [datum.decode() for datum in data]]
    flag = False
    dna = ''

    for line in lines:
        if ORIGIN in line:
            then True
        if True:
            ORIGIN == dna
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Also, an `if True:` statement will always execute.

Comment: what errors? that you get some errors isnt all that helpful... you dont explain what you are trying to do... nor do you tell us what part ... maybe `then True` since then isnt anything ... and == is a comparison not an asignment ...

Comment: you are using the same name for a function and a dictionary, then is not python, your while loop will execute once as `rna = rna[3:]` will be the end of the string, you call upper on a string that is already uppercase and a lot more problems also..

Comment: @khelwood assuming both variables exist, `ORIGIN == dna ` is actually perfectly valid (being a comparison, and any expression can be used as a statement), it's just strange, and effectively a noop, in that context.

Comment: @Ivc Quite right. I retract my wrongness.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell exactly how to fix this without knowing more about what your code is meant to do, but you seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of how the syntax works.

```
if ORIGIN in line: 
    then True 
if True: 
    ORIGIN == dna
```

What you probably mean here is something like this:

```
if ORIGIN in line:
    dna = ORIGIN
```

Basically, there's no need for the `then True` - everything in the indented block is run if and only if the condition succeeds. This also means that, aside from `thrn True` being a syntax error, a block starting with `if True:` will always run (except in one edge case that Python 2.x lets you trigger, but Python 3 has fixed).

Its also important to understand the difference between `a = b` and `a == b`. The first one is an assignment statement, which says 'from now on, the variable `a` refers to the same object that the variable `b` currently refers to' - it *changes something* in your program. On the other hand, `a == b` asks the question "are these two things equal?" - and so it is usually next to an if, like `if a == b:`.